# How to detect "power save mode" in Android "Xiaomi MIUI" devices?

Tags: java, android

How to detect "power save mode" in Android "Xiaomi MIUI" devices?

I use this code to detect "power save mode" in Android 5,6:

```
PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager)
    getActivity().getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP
    && powerManager.isPowerSaveMode())
{
    //power saving mode
}
```

But it's not work in "Xiaomi MIUI" devices.

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Comment: any solution on this?

Answer (score 2):

```
private void isPowerSaveModeHuaweiXiaomi(){
  if (Build.MANUFACTURER.equalsIgnoreCase("Xiaomi")) {
    try {
       int value = android.provider.Settings.System.getInt(getContext().getContentResolver(), "POWER_SAVE_MODE_OPEN");
               
            } catch (Settings.SettingNotFoundException e) {
                Log.d("Valor modo bateria:", "Error");
            }
        }else if (Build.MANUFACTURER.equalsIgnoreCase("Huawei")){
            try {
                int value = android.provider.Settings.System.getInt(getContext().getContentResolver(), "SmartModeStatus");
                
            } catch (Settings.SettingNotFoundException e) {
                Log.d("Valor modo bateria:", "Error");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please try to provide some explanation alongside your answer to make it more useful for future readers.

Answer (score 1):

For `Xiaomi` ROM, a system setting name `POWER_SAVE_MODE_OPEN` will be used to save the power save mode, so we can use this name to detect if it's on or off through the system settings api.

`android.provider.Settings.System#getInt(android.content.ContentResolver, java.lang.String, int)`

To monitor power save mode changing, we can register a intent receiver for `miui.intent.action.POWER_SAVE_MODE_CHANGED` or use `ContentObserver` for uri `content://settings/system/POWER_SAVE_MODE_OPEN`

see detail code implementations from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45743484/ispowersavemode-always-returns-false-for-huawei-devices/65682806#65682806).