# Detect Power Saving Mode on HUAWEI P30/Mate 10 Pro/Mate 20 pro android.provider.Settings$SettingNotFoundException SmartModeStatus

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, huawei-developers

Detecting whether the battery saving mode is enabled can be a challenge especially on Huawei devices. This question is a follow up question to this solution:

[isPowerSaveMode() always returns false for Huawei devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45743484/ispowersavemode-always-returns-false-for-huawei-devices/46041900#46041900)

The solution leads to an exception for HUAWEI P30 (and other) devices because the suggested setting name can not be found. How can the power saving mode be detected on these devices?