# How do I detect if battery saver is enabled on wear-os? (sdk 33/34)

Tags: android, kotlin, wear-os

I am trying to change the behavior of my wear os app programmatically based on whether or not battery saver is enabled.

I have tried getting the power system service and checking the `isPowerSaveMode` getter but, it always returns false regardless if power saver is enabled on the device

I have also tried listening to the intent ACTION_POWER_SAVE_MODE_CHANGED but, my receiver is never triggered

Are these the correct tactics to retrieve this information? If not, what is the correct way to retrieve this setting?

[image: image of the battery saver enabled]

(sample)

```kotlin
val powerManager = context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE) as PowerManager
println(powerManager.isPowerSaveMode) // is always false. I expect it to return true if battery saver is enabled
```

Comment: Did you check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45743484/ispowersavemode-always-returns-false-for-huawei-devices